# who, whoami, and "who am i"

Tags: who, whoami

I can understand the commands `who` and `whoami`, but what exactly happens when I type:

```
who am i
```

and

```
who am
```

I am on Ubuntu, nothing happens after them!

Why doesn't Linux / UNIX reply with an error message (something on the line of "unknown arguments" for `who`), or just reply with the output of `who`?

Answer (score 8):

If `whoami` doesn’t output anything, it probably indicates that your shell isn’t a login shell. There’s no user associated with `who`’s standard input, so `who` doesn’t output anything — that’s not an error as far as it’s concerned, so it doesn’t output an error message.

If you run

```
xterm -ls
```

to open a terminal with a login shell, you should find that `whoami` and `who am i` work fine. The same goes for a remote login using *e.g.* SSH.

Comment: You can also use the `login` command prior to issuing `whoami`, `who am i` or `who mom likes` etc, there appear to be many more variations in the arguments ;-).

Answer (score 6):

When you type:

```
$ who am i
```

In a shell (any shell), the first word (`who`) is parsed as "the command".
So, who is searched in the PATH, and after it is found, all other parameters/words/arguments are given to the command as arguments.

It is the job of `who` to interpret the arguments.

In fact, in linux, the [manual of who](https://linux.die.net/man/1/who) has this to say about 'am i':

> If ARG1 ARG2 given, -m presumed: 'am i' or 'mom likes' are usual.

So, such `who` will print only "hostname and user associated with stdin" (`-m` option).

If there is no user associated to stdin, nothing is printed.